# Erro na inclusão de dados PHP + MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

por gentileza poderiam me ajudar com o erro abaixo, estou tentando gravas esses dados do código em uma tabela porém quando peço pra gravar está retornando o erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function d/m/Y() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalPib\membros.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalPib\membros.php on line 7

Segue código:

```
<?php

include("conexaobanco.php");

If(isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nome", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datanascimento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y'(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "datanascimento", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $datacasamento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y'(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "datacasamento", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $dataadmissao = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y'(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "dataadmissao", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $datadesligamento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y'(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "datadesligamento", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $cargo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cargo", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $endereco = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "endereco", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $numero = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "numero", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $bairro = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "bairro", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $complemento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "complemento", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cidade", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $estado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "estado", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cep = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cep", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $profissao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "profissao", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $estadocivil = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "estadocivil", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $nomeconjuge = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nomeconjuge", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $batizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "batizado", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $databatismo = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y'(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "databatismo", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $igrejabatismo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "igrejabatismo", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "telefone", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    If(!$conn){
        die("Falha na conexão com o banco de dados, procure o administrador do sistema e informe o erro abaixo: ". "<br>" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    If(empty($nome)||empty($email)){
        echo "Preencha os campos corretamente!";
        exit;
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TB_MEMBROS (NOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO, DATA_CASAMENTO, DATA_ADMISSAO, DATA_DESLIGAMENTO, CARGO, ENDERECO, NUMERO, BAIRRO, COMPLEMENTO, CIDADE, ESTADO, CEP, PROFISSAO, ESTADO_CIVIL, NOME_CONJUGE, BATIZADO, DATA_BATISMO, IGREJA_BATISMO, EMAIL, TELEFONE) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$datanascimento->format('Y-m-d')."', '".$datacasamento->format('Y-m-d')."', '".$dataadmissao->format('Y-m-d')."', '".$datadesligamento->format('Y-m-d')."', '".$cargo."', '".$endereco."', '".$numero."', '".$bairro."', '".$complemento."', '".$cidade."', '".$estado."', '".$cep."', '".$profissao."', '".$estadocivil."', '".$nomeconjuge."', '".$batizado."', '".$databatismo->format('Y-m-d')."', '".$igrejabatismo."', '".$email."', '".$telefone."')";
    } If(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo "<script>Alert('Conta cadastrada com Sucesso!');</script>";
    } else {
        "Erro: " .$sql. "<br>" .mysqli_connect_error($conn);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas as linhas de datas estão `'d/m/Y'(` o correto seria `'d/m/Y', (`

O erro foi atenção mesmo, sem passar a vírgula, seria como se estivesse tentando invocar a função `d/m/Y`, que acredito não ser o que quer

Comment: boa, evitar tantos parentesis `$datanascimento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'datanascimento', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));`

Comment: Guilherme, realmente era essa virgula, isso que da fazer as pressas, porem agora está me retornando um erro na linha do insert - "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalPib\membros.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PortalPib\membros.php on line 37"

Comment: Provavelmente deve ser em alguma data, ao fazer `createFromFormat` da algum erro e retorna `false`. De vários `var_dump` e verifique os valores que aparece de cada variável

Comment: Resolvido Guilherme, os havia um campo sem preenchimento, quando passava ele em branco ele entendia que era um Booleano. Preenchi o campo e passou...Muito obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Cara, pelo erro ele não está reconhecendo a sua data, vou deixar um exemplo de sintaxe de data do php aqui.

```
  <?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                   // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
?>
```

e o link: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Comment: Olá Ricardo, muito obrigado, realmente estava retirei o formato da data e resolveu, porem para refeito de teste, deixei no banco um campo de data com formato date e outro como varchar, o que deixei varchar incluiu normalmente, o que deixei date ficou tudo zerado (0000-00-00), como consigo resolver isso?